# WebGL Weird Performance Drop in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl

I have been trying to learn WebGL so I have made a simple model loading script. I thought it was working all fine and dandy until I pulled up Chrome's devtools timeline and saw that I was getting ~20 FPS when rendering 100 models. The weird part was, the CPU was idle most of the time on each frame.

My first thought was that I must be GPU bound, which seemed unlikely because my shaders were short and not very complex. I tested with 10 models and again with only one, and that did increase performance, but I was still getting less than 40 FPS. I pulled up chrome://tracing, and saw that both my GPU wasn't doing much for each frame either. The majority of each frame in **CrGpuMain was filled with "Processing Swap"**, and CrBrowserMain spent nearly all of the time on glFinish (called by "CompositingIOSurfaceMac::DrawIOSurface").

**Processing Swap appears to be the major problem, not glFinish.**

So my question is, what is causing the browser to spend so much time on glFinish? Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

<del>Each model has 40608 elements and 20805 vertices</del>,

**Update - Corrected numbers of simplified mesh:**

- 3140 elements
- 6091 vertices

The models are pseudo-instanced so data is only passed to the GPU once per frame. Is the large number of vertices the problem?

The demo can be found [here](http://andars.github.io/WebGL-Test).

Rendering Code:

```
Thing.prototype.renderInstances = function(){
    if (this.loaded){
        var instance;
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexbuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalbuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, true, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indexbuffer);

        for(var i in this.instances){
            instance = this.instances[i];
            setMatrixUniforms(instance.matrix);
             gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, this.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

        }
    }

};
```

Vertex Shader Code:

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

    attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
    uniform mat4 uMMatrix;


    uniform mat4 uVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    uniform vec3 uLightDirection;
    varying float vLight;

    void main(void) {

        mat4 MVMatrix = uVMatrix*uMMatrix;
       //Toji's manual transpose
        mat3 normalMatrix = mat3(MVMatrix[0][0], MVMatrix[1][0], MVMatrix[2][0], MVMatrix[0][1], MVMatrix[1][1], MVMatrix[2][1], MVMatrix[0][2], MVMatrix[1][2], MVMatrix[2][2]); 

        gl_Position = uPMatrix*uVMatrix*uMMatrix*vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);

        vec3 lightDirection = uLightDirection*normalMatrix; 
        vec3 normal = normalize(aVertexNormal*normalMatrix);
        vLight = max(dot(aVertexNormal,uLightDirection),0.0);
    }
```

Comment: You can not pass 40608 elements and 20805 vertices to GPU once per frame

Comment: Here is a link: [WebGL Models](http://andars.github.io/WebGL-Models/). The vertices and elements number were actually array lengths (so actual amounts is one third), but I simplified mesh anyway. The problem is still present.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the "webkitRequestAnimationFrame" ... have you tried to use something different?

Comment: I get the same problem using both unprefixed requestAnimationFrame and setTimeout.

Comment: Then I think the problem is in shaders ... try to simplify them a little and see, if the performance improves.

Comment: I simplified the shaders as you suggested to the bare minimum to get something on the screen, but about:tracing still showed ~30 ms spent on "Processing Swap". I am not sure what this means.

Comment: Can't believe no one has asked this:  What is the system you are running on?  Full specs, including computer type, GPU, CPU, RAM, and screen resolution.